# Formatting year in D3 V4 to remove commas

Tags: d3.js

I am creating a line chart in D3 v4.

The x-axis is showing the year with commas like 1,998 and 1,999 instead of 1998 and 1999 etc. It is addig the thousand comma which is what I am trying to remove.

I am trying to remove the commas, but I have not been able to. tickformat is not working in v4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->     
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 80},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Amount); });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("australia.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Year = d.Year;
      d.Amount = +d.Amount;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year}));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Amount; })]);


  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // text label for the x axis
  svg.append("text")             
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                           (height + margin.top) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Year");

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // text label for the y axis
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
      .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Amount");  

});

</script>
</body>
```

And here is my csv file:

```
Year,Amount
1998,103323
1999,57914.9
2003,297.969
2004,921253.8
2007,169869.2
2008,44685.5
2010,86084.5
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `scaleTime` for x axis, not `scaleLinear`:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
```

You also should process your dataset this way:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Year = parseTime(d.Year);
  d.Amount = +d.Amount;
});
```

Check working example in the hidden snippet below:

```js
var dataAsCsv = `Year,Amount
1998,103323
1999,57914.9
2003,297.969
2004,921253.8
2007,169869.2
2008,44685.5
2010,86084.5`;


// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 80},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.Amount); });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv);


var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Year = parseTime(d.Year);
  d.Amount = +d.Amount;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Amount; })]);


// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline);

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// text label for the x axis
svg.append("text")             
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
        (height + margin.top) + ")")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Year");

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// text label for the y axis
svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Amount");
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
```